# open activity B in different package/folder from activity A in other package (main package)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, package

I'm currently working on a mobile app for our final project this semester. I want to know how to open an activity in a package from another activity from a different package.

Example:

FirstActivity in com.example.package1
SecondActivity in Package2
Package2 is inside in the com.example.package1

I want to open SecondActivity when a button is clicked in FirstActivity.

[The underlined class is the 2nd Activity and the highlighted one is the 1st activity.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfWp7.png)

[Here's the code from the MM_Play.class (first activity)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E22yt.png)

[Here's the code in the AndroidManifest.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsfmD.png)

Comment: Everything looks okay. Check for mismatched or duplicate id of views. Also, check the logs to see for any errors or warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this way by import second activity class in first activity

Inside onClickListener in First activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: Try to check both activity name is declared in manifest or not and also check the button attribute is it clickable or not, because the above line should work as you want in you project.or can u plz send ur code or button event which you have implemented

Comment: @EJPol Please add more details on how it doesn't work because nobody can guess what is your issue. The actual code from the answer had a few formatting error that would fail at compile time, but I corrected them. Now, the answer should fix you problem. If not, please add more details on how it doesn't work (compile issue, crash, nothing happens, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Add activity in your manifest file like this:

```
<activity
        android:name=". Your folder name where Second Activity is present then . 
        (Second Activity Name)"/>
```

In Java file like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivit.this,Second activity.class);
start activity(intent)
```